# Avoiding special characters that appear before and after a string while matching an exact word in ReGex

Tags: regex

I've looked into many existing solutions on exact match of a string but could not find a proper solution so I'm posting this question. Below is my ReGex for matching an exact string in python and it works well for most of the cases except when there is a special character before or after the string.

```
(?:^|\W)string(?:$|\W)
```

The above expression also matches `test@string.com`which I do not want. Basically I only want to match the word if it appears as a separate string and not in any other forms. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks I used (?<=\s|^)string+(?=\s|$) to solve my problem